# How to move a byteobject in Databricks to e.g. S3

Tags: databricks

I am working in Databricks/Python and I have a byte object given by a parameter "byte_object" and I want to move it to a S3 location `s3_path`. For a saved object in DBFS storage with path `dbfs_path` it can be done like:

```py
dbutils.fs.mv(dbfs_path, s3_path)
```

But my problem is that I want to move a byte object to S3, given by my parameter "byte_object" in Python. Not a file stored in DBFS, any ideas of how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your byte object could be represented as string, then you can use `dbutils.fs.put` directly with it ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html#dbutils-fs-put)).

Otherwise, you can write that byte object into a local file, and then use `dbutils.fs.mv` to move it to S3, something like this:

```
local_file = "/tmp/local_file"
with open(local_file, "wb") as f:
  f.write(byte_object)

dbutils.fs.mv(f"file:{local_file}", s3_path)
```

the main thing here is that you need to specify local file as `file:/__path__`, not simply `__path__` - it will search on DBFS without that prefix.